# Android Studio: Getters for editText

Tags: java, android, getter

I want to use the value of 2 editTexts from one activity in another. Here is my code so far. I am getting:

> java.lang.NullPointerException.

The Code:

```
public class AddJob extends AppCompatActivity{
    // vars
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private EditText editTextLat, editTextLng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_job);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.activityTitleAddJob);
        textView.setText("Add a Job");

        editTextLat = findViewById(R.id.editTextLat);
        editTextLng = findViewById(R.id.editTextLng);
    }

    public int getLatitude() {
        return new Integer(editTextLat.getText().toString());
    }

    public int getLongitude() {
        return new Integer(editTextLng.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

The Stack Trace:

[image]

Here is the code snippet from the map class:

```
AddJob aj = new AddJob();
int lat = aj.getLatitude();
int lng = aj.getLongitude();
Toast.makeText(aj, lat + " " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Can we have the stacktrace

Comment: provide stack trace, we are not wizards

Comment: I added the stack trace

Comment: Is because you call getLatitude() and editTextLat is null.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text. Furthermore, the trace suggests that you have another `Activity` named `map`. You'll want to post the relevant code from that, as well. You appear to be directly instantiating `AddJob` yourself, which you should never do. This would explain the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: How would I make editTextLat not null. I tried setting the text in onCreate().

Comment: [Also don't post links to code or stack traces. I've inserted the image into the post because It is important to keep all the info in the post to help folks who run into the same problem, but please supply text next time as @MikeM requested]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello would it not be better using an Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NEXTActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("latitude", lat);
            i.putExtra("longitude", lng);
            startActivity(i);
```

NEXTActivity

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    double latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
    double longitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");
```

Comment: I added your code into my activities, but I got a java.lang.NullPointerException.  It happened over here:    double latitude = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("latitude");

Comment: have you made variables for lat and lng
`public String lat; public String lng; `
 and also got the information from the edit text for each one.

Answer (score 2):

> Please read about the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). You should *never*
>   create an Activity directly with
>
> ```
> new MyActivity()
> ```

This will not launch any of the lifecycle events (`onCreate`, etc...) or bind it to a context, set a view hierarchy on it, or do any of the regular Activity things you may be expecting. Your program is returning null because `onCreate` is never called on the activity, and if you were to simply try to call it yourself it would likely crash.

If you want data from one activity to be available in another activity, an easy way to achieve this is to save the data in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) in the `AddJob` activity (whenever the values are updated) and access it in `MapActivity` from the `SharedPreferences`. You can also pass the data from one Activity to the next by adding data to the Intent when you launch it.

One advantage to using SharedPreferences here is that the user's choices will be saved from one app session to the next, and if you have multiple things that can launch the `MapActivity` they don't have to keep passing that data to it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create activity objects, you can start activity with Intent and pass data through it. Check out the relevant answer in the link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/10116426

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are instantiating the `AddJob` class. This may raise problems on the ***back-stack*** of android, which may create lifecycle management problems. So, as mentioned by @NoobAndroid, it is better to use the recommended way not to run into unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this code .

package com.example.cloudanalogy.introscreen;

import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private EditText editTextLat, editTextLng;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.activityTitleAddJob);
                textView.setText("Add a Job");
                editTextLat = findViewById(R.id.editTextLat);
                editTextLng = findViewById(R.id.editTextLng);
        }

            public int getLatitude() {
                return Integer.parseInt(editTextLat.getText().toString());
            }

            public int getLongitude() {
                return Integer.parseInt(editTextLng.getText().toString());
            }

    public void onclick(View view) {

        int lat = getLatitude();
        int lng = getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+lat+" and "+lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: if any problem you are facing regarding this please let me know .Thank you

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this fixes the problem - don't just post plain code blocks alone